# MSMQ 4.0 & .NET

Tags: .net, msmq

Is there a way that MSMQ would invoke a dll written in .NET?  For example, I would like to create a messaging queue that would accept messages with a label.  Then, can the queue invoke a different class object, based on the value in the label?

I looked a bit into triggers, but not sure if that is the only route that I can take.

Will I need to create a program/service that monitors the queue?  I thought that was the old way, but I can't seem to find any examples that do not have program/service that monitors the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options are pretty much either triggers or Windows Service. Should you go with triggers, you'd want to build an exe or a COM object wrapping your .Net DLL. Otherwise, you could build a service and register for an appropriate receive* event in MSMQ.
You could go the way of WCF with MSMQ channel underneath, but that likely requires that your client changes as well, as the messages will have to be formatted a certain way.

---

Bottom line you have two activation options: active, using triggers, and passive using Windows Service.

Comment: Technically, there is also a concept of service components, which can use MSMQ as transport, but that's an older technology that's not recommended, IMO. Just mentioning it for completeness.

Comment: Do you know of any good examples with Triggers?  I google'd for it and found a bunch, but not as effective ... got an example app going, but can't get it to fire off.  Also, any examples of service components?

Comment: @KP: [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/MSMQ_triggers.aspx) uses both triggers and rule binding, so it may be helpful.

Comment: @KP: [and this one](http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0003021) talks about queued components (Triggers are implemented as queued components, AFAIK). I don't know how much .Net support there is for QC, hence my not recommending this approach.

Comment: Triggers and Queued Components are totally unrelated technologies. 
1 - Triggers - perform action when message arrives. 2 - QC - Call a component's method using MSMQ instead of RPC.

Comment: @John Breakwell: John, I agree with what you are saying specifically. However, we are trying to help OP solve somewhat of a broader problem. That's why I'm proposing WCF over MSMQ, QC over COM+, Windows Service with Listeners and MSMQ Triggers, which as you said are all different in the way they work--just trying to offer a broad swath of choices, with the notion that one will help.

Comment: @John Breakwell: I've read somewhere that the actual MSMQ trigger functionality has been implemented as QCs themselves in MSMQ, but that information may not true. I think that may have sounded confusing in my earlier comment. In either case, I'm agreeing that the two aren't related solutions to OP's problem.

Comment: I'm not complaining about your choices of solution for the OP but bad information needs to be corrected or it just perpetuates. If you read somewhere that triggers and QC were linked then whoever wrote it was wrong, end of story.